# How to auto format wrong json with code in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I as trying to parse a json response. However, there is a trailing comma at the end of the reponse which throws an error while decoding it. How do i automatically format if from code such that it removes the comma and validates it?

```
[{"id" : "9991","last_message" : "How about tomorrow then?","members" : ["John", "Daniel", "Rachel"],"topic" : "pizza night", "modified_at" : 1599814026153}, {"id" : "9992","last_message" : "I will send them to you asap","members" : ["Raphael"],"topic" : "slides", "modified_at" : 1599000026153}, {"id" : "9993","last_message" : "Can you please?","members" : ["Mum", "Dad", "Bro"],"topic" : "pictures", "modified_at" : 1512814026153},]
```

**Error**

```
D/EGL_emulation( 7121): app_time_stats: avg=32.94ms min=4.95ms max=83.26ms count=30
E/flutter ( 7121): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 435)
E/flutter ( 7121): ..."Mum", "Dad", "Bro"],"topic" : "pictures", "modified_at" : 1512814026153},]
```

Comment: can you show how you are converting then response?

Comment: done. please review

Answer (score 0):

So, you should give some code from source, but I think you're using a `http.Response` object so you can do something like this:

```dart
String bodyRes = response.body;
bodyRes = bodyRes.endsWith(',]') ? bodyRes.replaceFirst(',]', ']', bodyRes.length - 2) : bodyRes;
```

Comment: I get an error

Dart Unhandled Exception: type 'Response' is not a subtype of type 'String', stack trace: #0

Comment: I've edited the answer, try this way